# Wildfly Resteasy gives me 404 error and no logging

Tags: rest, jboss, resteasy, wildfly

I have a very simple RESTeasy example running wildfly 8.2 on Mac.

It contains only two classes:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApp extends Application {
}
```

=

```
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/test")
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class TestTheRest extends Application {

   @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   public Response getBookingDetails() {
        String hello = "Hi";
        return Response.ok(hello).build();
  }

}
```

Browsing to /warname gives me "forbidden" which should be ok while trying with "/warname/test" will return a 404 not found. Also in the server.log i can see just nothing when making requests ??
Did I miss something here ?

```
[0m [0m19:03:54,777 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /logicshop
[0m [0m19:03:54,814 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "logicshop.war" (runtime-name : "logicshop.war")
[0m [0m19:03:54,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
[0m [0m19:03:54,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
[0m [0m19:03:54,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started in 3018ms - Started 262 of 317 services (92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
[0mConnected to server
[2015-01-15 07:03:54,836] Artifact logicshop: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[0m19:03:54,899 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017535: Unregistered web context: /logicshop
[0m [0m19:03:54,918 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
[0m [0m19:03:54,966 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment logicshop.war (runtime-name: logicshop.war) in 71ms
[0m [0m19:03:55,013 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "logicshop.war" (runtime-name: "logicshop.war")
[0m [0m19:03:55,079 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "logicshop.war" (runtime-name: "logicshop.war")
[0m [0m19:03:55,138 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /logicshop
[0m [0m19:03:55,149 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "logicshop.war" (runtime-name : "logicshop.war")
[0m[2015-01-15 07:03:55,165] Artifact logicshop: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-01-15 07:03:55,165] Artifact logicshop: Deploy took 329 milliseconds
```

Comment: Check `localhost_access_log` log file on server to see the HTTP requests & their response codes.

Comment: Guess this is a Tomcat logfile isn't it ? I don't have this in JBOSS / Wildfly

Comment: You just hadn't enabled it then. See [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/how-do-you-configure-jboss-to-enable-http-logging)

Comment: there is no such config file in wildfly and your link says Tomcat as well ;-)

Comment: Looks as if the Resource annotation are not scanned ?

Comment: Your resource class shouldn't extend `Application` - not sure if this is related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your hint you're right. Did not solve the problem though.

Comment: EDIT: I also have the problem when running the javaee7 example rest enpoint: https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaxrs/jaxrs-endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I found this behavior to happen if persistence.xml is placed in "WEB-INF" instead of "META-INF". Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had some dao and entity with hibernate dependencies. 
I removed those and now it works ??